# Debugging for Elisp threads?

Tags: debugging, async, threading

Let's say some package does

```
(make-thread
  (lambda ()
    (message "Started thread.")
    (error "Fit happens.")
    (message "Finished thread.")))
```

Regardless of `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, the error will be silently ignored. Even on

```
(thread-join (make-thread ...))
```

the error will not be handled in any manner. `(thread-last-error)` can give access to the error object, but it is subject to race conditions.

Is it possible to run the debugger instead, when there is an error in threads?